# TSQL DateTime DataType - fractional seconds vs milliseconds

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

Wanting to get all records from a single day. So everything between `2013-03-05 00:00:00.000` and `2013-03-05 23:59:59.999`. We're getting overlap at the backend with things that happened at `2013-03-06 00:00:00.000`.

So, in testing I run in SSMS:

```
select cast('2013-03-05 23:59:59.999' as datetime)
select cast('2013-03-05 23:59:59.996' as datetime)
select cast('2013-03-05 23:59:59.994' as datetime)
```

And get:

```
2013-03-06 00:00:00.000
2013-03-05 23:59:59.997
2013-03-05 23:59:59.993
```

The millisecond part comes back off by a little. In the case of the first line it really matters. Because I don't want 2013-03-06 00:00:00.000 - I want a millisecond before midnight.

TSQL states in documentation that it uses fractional seconds as opposed to .Net datetime which uses milliseconds. This would seem to be a syntax difference only but if you really care about millisecond precision in TSQL are you forced to use `DateTime2` across the board.  Casting from `datetime2` to `datetime` still mucks things up by a couple milliseconds.

In c# `DateTime.Parse("03/5/2013 23:59:59.999").Millisecond` still returns 999.

Am I interpreting this all right? If I care about millisecond precision am I stuck with `datetime2` only.

Normally that would be an easy fix but in this case we're using a Microsoft system function that receives `datetime` as parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of specifying 23:59:59.999 you must specify 23:59:59.997 due to rounding.

The far better way would be to :

```
WHERE MyDate >= '2013-03-05' AND MyDate < '2013-03-06'
```

Since this captures ALL activity on 2013-03-05